# Format of TYPE_INT_RGB and TYPE_INT_ARGB

Tags: java, colors, rgb, argb

Could anyone explain for me how java stores color in TYPE_INT_RGB and TYPE_INT_ARGB ?
Do these lines of code work properly for calculating red, green and blue ?

```
int red= (RGB>>16)&255;
int green= (RGB>>8)&255;
int blue= (RGB)&255;
```

And what about TYPE_INT_ARGB ? How can I get red, green and blue from TYPE_INT_ARGB?

Comment: for nicer code, 255 could be `0xff` or `0b1111_1111`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `TYPE_INT_ARGB` represents Color as an `int` (4 bytes) with alpha channel in bits 24-31, red channels in 16-23, green in 8-15 and blue in 0-7.

The `TYPE_INT_RGB` represents Color as an `int` (4 bytes) int the same way of `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, but the alpha channel is ignored (or the bits 24-31 are 0).

Look the javadoc of [java.awt.Color](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) and [java.awt.image.BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Comment: I didn't knew about these thingies before :-) Happy to know someone else has searched this for you :-)

Answer (score 12):

You are correct for TYPE_INT_RGB. The equivalent TYPE_INT_ARGB code would be:

```
int rgb = rgbColor.getRGB(); //always returns TYPE_INT_ARGB
int alpha = (rgb >> 24) & 0xFF;
int red =   (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >>  8) & 0xFF;
int blue =  (rgb      ) & 0xFF;
```

Spelling out the color elements for the bytes from most significant to least significant, you get ARGB, hence the name.

Answer (score 0):

These are constant values that indicate the color model of an instance of `BufferedImage`. These values do not themselves store the color.