# How Do I Change 4 Separate Int Values For Alpha, Red, Green, Blue into TYPE_INT_RGB?

Tags: java, image, bufferedreader

thank you for your time :). I have already taken a look at [Format of TYPE_INT_RGB and TYPE_INT_ARGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001211/format-of-type-int-rgb-and-type-int-argb) and now know how to convert this TYPE_INT_RGB into 4 separate values, but if I were to do a modification to each (say add 20 to each, so Alpha+=20, red+=20, and so on) how would I recombine these values into this TYPE_INT_RGB formatting? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
// to extract the components into individual ints.
int argb = something();
int red = 0xFF & ( argb >> 16);
int alpha = 0xFF & (argb >> 24);
int blue = 0xFF & (argb >> 0 );
int green = 0xFF & (argb >> 8 );

// to recreate the argb
int argb = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16 ) | (green<<8) | blue;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should work

```
int RGB = alpha;
RGB = (RGB << 8) + red;
RGB = (RGB << 8) + green;
Rgb = (RGB << 8) + blue;
```

There's another way without bit shifting, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

This one is okay, too:

```
int rgba = new java.awt.Color(r,g,b,a).getRGB();
```

Comment: You are absolutely amazing! Thanks! Oh, found one small issue with this, the order was a bit off, here is the syntax that worked for me:

        int newRGB = alpha;
        newRGB = (newRGB << 8) + red;
        newRGB = (newRGB << 8) + green;
        newRGB = (newRGB << 8) + blue;

Comment: Your bit shifting is wrong and `Color` does not have `toRGB`. I strongly believe that bitwise manipulation should be avoided wherever possible and `Color` allows one to do so.

Comment: `Color` has `getRGB()` as of JDK1.0? It returns `int`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) for this.

```
int ARGB = new Color(red, green, blue, alpha).getRGB();
```

I guess you are using bitwise operations to pull out the individual color channels, but again the `Color` class can hide those gory details.

```
Color color = new Color(ARGB);
int red = color.getRed();
int green = color.getGreen();
// etc.
```