# Converting from TYPE_INT_ARGB colour integer to a hex/RGB one

Tags: java, colors, rgb, bufferedimage, argb

I have an integer representing a colour in ARGB. How do I convert this into a hex colour format/RGB colour format using java?

Comment: Is there alpha? If not just convert it to hex and ignore the first byte.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "convert this into a hex colour format"? Do you want to split the int value into 4 (or 3 for RGB) bytes?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001211/format-of-type-int-rgb-and-type-int-argb